# Asus RT-N66U Port Forwarding with VPN to PIA

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding

I have an Asus RT-N66U router (using the latest firmware) that is connected to my ISPs fiber modem using PPPoE.  I have signed up for VPN access to PIA and setup the router to connect using its VPN client.  I also have a number of ports that I've opened for various applications in my network.  Now, both of these are working correctly - when used separately.  When I activate the VPN client all of the port forwarding stops working both through my normal IP address and through my VPN endpoint IP address.  Even with the VPN connection up, should I not be able to still make connections to my regular local IP address?

EDIT: For everyone pointing me to "Access my home network printer while I am using VPN to connect to work" - this is not the same as my question.  In that question, the user could not connect to his printer INSIDE his network while having an active VPN link.  My issue is having connections from the Internet INTO my network while the VPN link is up.  For example, if I have my VPN link connected to PIA, I cannot access my cameras from my work computer because my router just rejects the connection on port 9000.

Comment: The whole concept of a VPN is that you're joining a private network. Quite simply you're not on your network anymore, and I think it'd be a rather large security hole if your PC/home network could be used as a hop into a **private** network.

Comment: Second paragraph https://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/02/21/access-local-and-vpn-network-simultaneously/

Comment: @TechnikEmpire:  Thanks for the links but they don't exactly deal with my situation.  First, my router is creating the VPN link, not my computer.  Second, it is not an issue of not being able to access resources inside my network once the link has been created.  The problem is that the router no longer accepts traffic coming from the Internet to the local IP address (as opposed to the PIA endpoint IP address).

Comment: So, normally when my VPN link is down, my IP address is something like 208.208.208.208 and I can connect from the internet to port 9999 to view my DVR.  When the VPN connection is turned on, my PIA endpoint address is 168.168.168.168 but connections to port 9000 don't work and neither do connections to 208.208.208..208:9000.